# Cannot include header file rometadataresolution.h

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime

I'm trying to call the [RoParseTypeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438434.aspx) function. According to the documentation, I need to `#include <rometadataresolution.h>`. Trying to do so results in the following error message<sup>1</sup>:

> c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\winrt\rometadataresolution.h(10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cor.h': No such file or directory

The following code can be used to replicate the issue:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <rometadataresolution.h>

int CALLBACK wWinMain( HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int )
{
    return 0;
}
```

On inspection of the SDK installations on my machine, the header file *'cor.h'* is missing from the SDK versions 10.0.10150.0, 10.0.10240.0, 10.0.10586.0, and 10.0.15063.0. It is present for version 10.0.14393.0.

How do I use `RoParseTypeName` with the latest Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.0?

---

<sup>1</sup> For reference, the first non-comment lines of *'rometadataresolution.h'* are:

```
#pragma once
#include <cor.h>
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://github.com/DarthTon/Blackbone/issues/113

Check if `cor.h` is conditionally included in your case too. If so, figure out if you can do without it.

Comment: @patatahooligan: `#include <cor.h>` is the second non-comment line in *'rometadataresolution.h'* (the first being `#pragma once`). There's no way for me to skip this line, regardless of whether I do in fact need *'cor.h'* or not.